# Efecto ease-in en imágenes cargadas con Unveil

Tags: jquery, css

Estoy usando el plugin Unveil (de Luis Almeida) para hacer una precarga de imágenes pesadas. Es bastante sencillo de implementar y todo funciona más o menos como esperaba. Sin embargo, según la documentación, hay una forma de, una vez las imágenes se han cargado, mostrarlas con un efecto ease-in con CSS.

El HTML que tengo es

```
<div class="col-xs-12 workImage">
    <img src="images/spinner.gif" data-src="pictures/pic3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
</div>
```

El JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.workImage').find('img').unveil(-300, function() {
        $(this).css( { 'opacity': 1} );
    });
});
```

y el CSS

```
.workImage img{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
 }
```

El problema es que con este código el efecto de fundido se aplica a toda la etiqueta `<img>` incluido el spinner y no únicamente a la imagen que queremos mostrar. No sé si me explicado bien

Cuando visitamos la página, Unveil aplica el efecto a la etiqueta `<img>`, por lo que el spinner se muestra con un fundido mientras se carga la imagen. Una vez ésta se ha cargado la muestra de golpe y no con el efecto, que ya se usó al cargar la etiqueta `<img>` y fue aplicado al spinner.

La documentación dice que se puede llamar a la función callback que se ejecutará una vez la imagen ha sido desvelada, y no estoy seguro si estoy entendiendo esta parte de forma correcta, ya qu eno hago ninguna llamada a la función `callback()` . La verdad que esta parte no se como hacerla ni si es el motivo de este problema, ¿alguien podría echarme una mano con esto?

Esta es la página de Unveil donde se puede ver el uso y la documentación

http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1):

Si inspeccionas los estilos de las imágenes en el [Demo](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/) podras ver que el `spinner` esta como `background-image` de los tags `img`.

El detalle es que en su demo no usa esta técnica.

Una solución para tu caso podría ser la siguiente:

- Establecer para los `.workImage` (contenedor de las `img`) el `spinner` como imagen de fondo.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.workImage').find('img').unveil(300, function() {
        $(this).css( { 'opacity': 1} );
    });
});
```

```css
.workImage {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(//stanfy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/1-V3h-VWthi5lL0QySF6qZPw.gif);
}
.workImage img {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
/**
 * jQuery Unveil
 * A very lightweight jQuery plugin to lazy load images
 * http://luis-almeida.github.com/unveil
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * Copyright 2013 Luís Almeida
 * https://github.com/luis-almeida
 */

;(function($) {

  $.fn.unveil = function(threshold, callback) {

    var $w = $(window),
        th = threshold || 0,
        retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1,
        attrib = retina? "data-src-retina" : "data-src",
        images = this,
        loaded;

    this.one("unveil", function() {
      var source = this.getAttribute(attrib);
      source = source || this.getAttribute("data-src");
      if (source) {
        this.setAttribute("src", source);
        if (typeof callback === "function") callback.call(this);
      }
    });

    function unveil() {
      var inview = images.filter(function() {
        var $e = $(this);
        if ($e.is(":hidden")) return;

        var wt = $w.scrollTop(),
            wb = wt + $w.height(),
            et = $e.offset().top,
            eb = et + $e.height();

        return eb >= wt - th && et <= wb + th;
      });

      loaded = inview.trigger("unveil");
      images = images.not(loaded);
    }

    $w.scroll(unveil);
    $w.resize(unveil);

    unveil();

    return this;

  };

})(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);
</script>
<div class="col-xs-12 workImage">
    <img data-src="//lorempixel.com/g/800/500/city/1" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Marcos, gracias por responder. Me gusta tu aporte y creo que los tiros van por ahí, sin embargo me temo que no muestra la imagen con el fundido, incluso me temo que no está haciendo ni siquiera la precarga realmente. Puedes echar un vistazo aquí http://tanaanstudio.com/testDipesh2/ Ten en cuenta que los tumbs se cargan con lazyLoad, otro plugin distinto. Si pinchas en cualquiera de las cuatro primeras imágenes, verás que se despliega un div con más contenido donde se encuentran las imágenes que cargo con Unveil. Sólo las fotos de paisajes son las más pesadas, donde podrás ver el efecto

Comment: El contenido de la primera imágen es el único que tiene el HTML para que funcione con tu propuesta, aunque los demás también toman el spinner como background además de como src, por eso verás dos antes de mostrar la imagen.

Comment: @tanaan, este plugin no realiza en ningún momento un `pre-loading`, sólo controla, mediante cálculos en base a la posición de la imagen respecto del `scroll`, si la imagen debe ser visualizada o no. En mi ejemplo, se puede percibir el efecto. Te recomiendo que revises tu `CSS` y `markup` actual, ya que seguramente algo en el mismo esta afectando el correcto funcionamiento.

Comment: Gracias por responder de nuevo. El código lo he sustituido por el que sugieres y no hace el fundido en ningún momento. el tema de la precarga tendré que revisarlo entonces porque está pensado para una página que tendrá muchas imágenes y todas muy pesadas y necesito controlar el tiempo de carga de la página. Ignoro si has visitado el enlace que te he pasado, el código es más complejo que el que he posteado aquí. Te agradezco aún así tu ayuda y tu tiempo.

Comment: @tanaan, he visitado el enlace y he podido apreciar el efecto en todas las imágenes que se cargan al presionar sobre cualquier imagen "Neymar Jr.". Realmente no se que es lo que no te esta funcionando (Ahora justo al ultimo no dejo de funcionar el `spinner`)

Comment: he vuelto a una versión anterior ahora mismo. Básicamente quería mostrar el spinner y que el efecto de fundido se haga cuando la imagen ha sido cargada. He estado comprobando las cargas, quizás me he explicado mal anteriormente. Como decía, al ser una página donde las imágenes van a ser muy pesada no puedo pedirlas al servidor todas de una al arrancar index o tardaría muchísimo en cargar la página, pero Unveil hace las peticiones solo cuando tienen que ser mostradas así que creo que me valdrá este plugin.Lo del fundido no prioritario pero seguiré investigando.Gracias de nuevo.